# Adding more onto an esc_url

Tags: urls, buddypress

I have an esc_url that creates a link to buddypress profiles depending on the author of the post which returns like this http://www.mywebsite.com/members/username/  I want to make it so it returns "posts" at the end of the url too like so, http://www.mywebsite.com/members/username/posts

The code I have.

```
esc_url( bp_core_get_userlink( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $no_anchor = false, $just_link = true )),
```

I tried placing the following

```
&& 'posts'
|| 'posts'
```

after the

```
bp_core_get_userlink( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
```

and other parts of the code line but my PHP isn't great so I'm not sure exactly how && and || works. Worth a try though. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate strings, PHP uses the [concatenation operator `.`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Thus, to append a string to the current user link, you can use

```
bp_core_get_userlink( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), false, true ) . '/posts/'
```

Note that I've removed the first part of the assignment from the `$no_anchor` and `$just_link` parameters, as the values should be passed, and not the assignments themselves.

In general, I suggest you start by reading a few [basic PHP tutorials](https://www.google.nl/search?q=basic%20php%20tutorial).

Comment: Cheers, worked perfectly.